# Login fail and authorization error with REST in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to create an default admin on boot by default for my loopback node.js app with cloudant as database. But every time I start the app, the login fails for the default admin created. Is there something wrong with the code due to which the data is not stored in the cloudant database or something else?

Also the authorized REST tasks won't work if I manually create an Admin, instead a 401 Authorization required error is thrown.

common/models/user.json is as follows:

```
{
      "name": "user",
      "base": "User",
      "idInjection": true,
      "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "image": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "phone": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        }
      },
      "validations": [],
      "relations": {
        "comments": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "comments",
          "foreignKey": "userId"
        },
        "watchLists": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "watchList",
          "foreignKey": "userId"
        }
      },
      "acls": [
        {
          "accessType": "*",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "$everyone",
          "permission": "DENY"
        },
        {
          "accessType": "READ",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "admin",
          "permission": "ALLOW"
        },
        {
          "accessType": "READ",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "$owner",
          "permission": "ALLOW"
        },
        {
          "accessType": "EXECUTE",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "admin",
          "permission": "ALLOW",
          "property": "create"
        },
        {
          "accessType": "WRITE",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "admin",
          "permission": "ALLOW"
        }
      ],
      "methods": {}
    }
```

server/boot/script.js is as follows:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
var cloudantDB = app.dataSources.cloudant;
cloudantDB.automigrate('user', function (err) {
if (err) throw (err);
var user = app.models.user;

user.find({ where: { username: 'Admin' }, limit: 1 }, function (err, users) {

  if (!users) {
    user.create([
      { username: 'Admin', email: 'admin@admin.com', password: 'abcdef' }
    ], function (err, users) {
      if (err) return debug(err);

      var Role = app.models.Role;
      var RoleMapping = app.models.RoleMapping;

      Role.destroyAll();
      RoleMapping.destroyAll();

      //create the admin role
      Role.find({
        name: 'admin'
      }, function (err, results) {
        if (err) return debug(err);

        //make Admin an admin
        if (results.length < 1) {
        //create the admin role
        Role.create({
          name: 'admin'
        }, function(err, role) {
          if (err) throw (err);
           //make admin
          role.principals.create({
            principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
            principalId: users[0].id
          }, function(err, principal) {
            if (err) throw (err);
          });
        });
      }
    });
  })
}
else {

}

});
});
};
```

server/datasources.json is as follows:

```
{
  "db": {
  "name": "db",
  "connector": "memory"
},
"cloudant": {
  "host": "de945f4f-c2d2-41d8-ab3c-925e3e1f8e15-bluemix.cloudant.com",
  "port": 443,
  "database": "show-guide-database",
  "username": "de945f4f-c2d2-41d8-ab3c-925e3e1f8e15-bluemix",
  "password": "55862b46942ecd959092648262b18c3ac6f7439b7025e8bdd5a4e303779f1641",
  "name": "cloudant",
  "connector": "cloudant"
},
"images": {
  "name": "images",
  "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
  "provider": "filesystem",
  "root": "./client/"
 }
}
```

server/model-config.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "_meta": {
 "sources": [
   "loopback/common/models",
   "loopback/server/models",
   "../common/models",
   "./models"
 ],
 "mixins": [
   "loopback/common/mixins",
   "loopback/server/mixins",
   "../common/mixins",
   "./mixins"
 ]
 },
 "User": {
  "dataSource": "db"
 },
 "AccessToken": {
  "dataSource": "db",
  "public": false
 },
 "ACL": {
  "dataSource": "cloudant",
  "public": false
 },
 "RoleMapping": {
  "dataSource": "cloudant",
  "public": false
 },
 "Role": {
  "dataSource": "cloudant",
  "public": false
 },
 "shows": {
  "dataSource": "cloudant",
  "public": true,
  "$promise": {},
  "$resolved": true
 },
 "comments": {
  "dataSource": "cloudant",
  "public": true
 },
 "user": {
  "dataSource": "cloudant",
  "public": true,
  "$promise": {},
  "$resolved": true
 },
 "watchList": {
  "dataSource": "cloudant",
  "public": true
 },
 "series": {
  "dataSource": "cloudant",
  "public": true
 },
 "container": {
  "dataSource": "images",
  "public": true
 }
}
```

Comment: You forgot about async calling methods. `destroyAll`, `find` are async and you call like a sync method. Synchronize all of them using `async` module to keep orders between calling

Comment: could you please elaborate???

Answer (score 0):

You only need to check the admin account existence. No need to destroying anything.

```
//server/boot/admin.js

'use strict';

var async = require('async');

module.exports = function(app, cb) {
  /*
   * Adding necessary admin `User`s to database.
   */

  var User = app.models.User;
  var Role = app.models.Role;
  var RoleMapping = app.models.RoleMapping;

  var admin = {
    username: 'admin',
    email: 'admin@admin.com',
    password: '123456'
  };

  User.count({email: admin.email}, function(err, count) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    if (count > 0) return cb(null);
    User.create(admin, adminHandler);
  });

  var adminHandler = function(err, user) {
    if (err) return cb(err);

    async.waterfall([
      function(callback) {
        Role.findOne({where: {name: 'ADMIN'}}, function(err, role) {
          if (err) return callback(err);
          if (role) return callback(null, role);
          Role.create({name: 'ADMIN'}, callback);
        });
      },
      function(role, callback) {
        role.principals.create({
          principalType: RoleMapping.User,
          principalId: user.id
        }, callback);
      }
    ], function(err, result) {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      cb(null);
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: done but still not working. I don't know but somehow the script.js file inside boot folder is not executed on app start.